# Best way to join 2 API data sources into 1 react table?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-table, react-table-v7

I need data from 2 different APIs, both support pagination.

How can I display the joined data in a table in a performant way?

I need to join on their `id`, but one API returns less data than the other, so I cannot simply match 1 by 1. I need to implement a filter.

Is the only way to brute force map data source A to B?

Comment: Do you have any code yet? - if you do, could you provide these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the data comes from two different APIs and you are making to separate requests you have a number of options. My personal preference is to have `state` in your controller in which you `map` each response by `id` and then you can select the additional data by id:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { keyBy } from 'lodash';

function TableComponent(props) {
  // Destructure your props...I'm assuming you pass some id into fetch data
  const { id } = props;
  
  // State
  const [tableData, setTableData] = useState([]);

  // Load data when id changes
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData()
  }, [id]);

  async function fetchData() {
    // Get your data from each source
    const apiData_A = await fetchDataFromAPI_A(id);
    const apiData_B = await fetchDataFromAPI_B(id);
    // Key each data set by result ids
    const resultsMappedById_A = keyBy(apiData_A, 'id');
    const resultsMappedById_B = keyBy(apiData_B, 'id');
    // Combine data into a single set
    // this assumes your getting same results from each api
    const combinedDataSet = Object.keys(resultsMappedById_A)
      .reduce((acc, key) => {
        // Destructure results together, merging objects
        acc.push({
          ...resultsMappedById_A[key],
          ...resultsMappedById_B[key]
        });
        return acc;
      }, []);
    setTableData(combinedDataSet);
  }

  async function fetchDataFromAPI_A(id) {
    // Fetch your data and return results
  }

  async function fetchDataFromAPI_A(id) {
    // Fetch your data and return results
  }

  function renderTableRow(data) {
    return (
      <tr>
        <td>{data.id}</td>
        <td>{data.apiAProp}</td>
        <td>{data.apiBProp}</td>
      </tr>
    );
  }


  return (
   <table>
     { tableDataSet.map(renderTableRow) }
   </table>
  );
}
```

Note, there are probably more efficient ways to do this depending on how you're fetching data and what the responses hold, but the concept provided here should do the trick assuming my assumptions are correct based on the information you have provided.