# How to combine 2 or more API sources into one table (React, HTML)

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, html-table

So I have 3 API sources that return data in this format

```
firstSource = [{month, endDate, expectedPrice}] ->array of 12 objects
secondSource = [{month, value}] ->array of 12 objects
thirdSource = [{month, value}] ->array of 12 objects
```

example:

```
secondSource = [
{month: 1, value: 234.22},
{month: 2, value: 123.58},
{month: 3, value: 255.35},
...
...
you get the idea
]
```

I've come across [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64328603/best-way-to-join-2-api-data-sources-into-1-react-table) that uses lodash library. This is all well, but I'm interested in a solution that doesn't require external libraries. So basically, I want to achieve the same thing the person from the lodash solution did -> **combine all three data sources into one and then use that to display the data in `<table>` element**, only without using external libraries, e.g. lodash.

Expected output:

```
combined = [
{month, endDate, expectedPrice, secondSourceValue, thirdSourceValue}
]
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you trying to merge the arrays, or merge the data from separate sources into one set of data based on a key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what's the problem to try something like this?

```
let combinedData = []

firstSource.forEach((element, index) => {
    combinedData[index] = {
      month: element.month,
      endDate: element.endDate,
      expectedPrice: element.expectedPrice,
      secondSourceValue: secondSource[index].value,
      thirdSourceValue: thirdSource[index].value
}    
});
```

You only have to check if the second and third sources have the same length with the main.

Comment: This works great. The only thing bothering me now is to define the type of this new combined array since im using typescript. All three data sources have their own type

Comment: Got it. Fixed the typescript issue.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `array.map`to merge multiple arrays of objects and create a new array with properties of all objects.

Do note that, in this case, the length of all the arrays should be the same.

```js
let arr1 = [{
    month: 1,
    value: 234.22,
    date: 'JAN'
  },
  {
    month: 2,
    value: 123.58,
    date: 'FEB'
  },
  {
    month: 3,
    value: 255.35,
    date: 'MARCH'
  }
]

let arr2 = [{
    month: 1,
    property: 1
  },
  {
    month: 2,
    property: 2
  },
  {
    month: 3,
    property: 3
  }
]

let arr3 = [{
    month: 1,
    property: 9
  },
  {
    month: 2,
    property: 8
  },
  {
    month: 3,
    property: 7
  },
]


let combinedArr = arr1.map((item, index) => {
  return {
    ...item,
    ...arr2[index],
    ...arr3[index]
  }
})

console.log(combinedArr)
```

Comment: I need to join them on the `month` key, this only adds them up together

Comment: Can you include the expected output in your question.

Comment: Added it in the main post.